# Monitor the availability of Marathon Framework

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring, apache-mesos

I am using Mesos - Marathon for App deployment and availability, but sometimes marathon freezes. I tried to monitor the tcp port, but during the freeze port is open and thus not able to detect the failure?

Any suggestions for the monitoring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Mesos API](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/monitoring/)?

You could easily monitor it periodically and get alerts in your cellphone by using a monitoring solution like **Pandora FMS**: [pandorafms.org](http://pandorafms.org)

Comment: Thanks @santimviejo, did exactly the same, built a small clojure healthcheck program to check the api. :)

Comment: Great stuff! I'm glad this helped :)